# Spell-check in Aquamacs Emacs won't work: "Wrong endian order."

Tags: macos, emacs, spell-checking, aquamacs

This is aquamacs 1.5 on a macbook.  Exact error when I try to spell-check:

Error: The file "/Library/Application Support/cocoAspell/aspell6-en-6.0-0//en-common.rws" is not in the proper format. Wrong endian order.

ADDED: I indeed had the wrong version of cocoAspell.  But installing the right version didn't work until I actually wiped (or renamed) /Library/Application Support/cocoAspell and reinstalled from scratch.  That's what had thrown me for a loop.  Thanks for the quick answers!  Stackoverflow rocks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have the wrong version of the coco interface to Aspell for your mac.

Check this site and download the appropriate version (PowerPC/Intel):
http://people.ict.usc.edu/~leuski/cocoaspell/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but this page seems similar:
http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/AquamacsFAQ
(search for "format" on that page to find the relevant part)

Have you been using fink to install an old version of aspell like in this posting?

Comment: Not fink but I think the contents of /Library were copied over from my old non-intel mac.  The cocoAspell directory had to be manually wiped before installing the new version.  This should probably be considered a bug in the cocoAspell installer.